# reference the composite primary key

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

friend's I create a table with composite primary key having three columns,Then I create the child table which refere's  only two columns.this will make the error..please help me to refere only two columns from the base table.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
( SID NUMBER
, NAME VARCHAR2(20)
, DEPT VARCHAR2(20)
, CARD_F NUMBER
, CARD_S NUMBER
, PRIMARY KEY (SID, CARD_F, CARD_S)
); 

CREATE TABLE MASTER
( BOOKNO NUMBER
, CARD_S NUMBER
, FOREIGN KEY (BOOKNO) 
    REFERENCES STUDENT(CARD_F)
);
```

Comment: Why don't you define the `SID` as the primary key? And if the `CARD_F` and `CARD_S` are uniquely identifying a student, have them as unique keys?

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key is by defition a key in another table. You can't reffer a tuple that is not key.

See below the Foreign Key page at W3schools:

> A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

([link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp))

Comment: A foreign key should point to either the `PRIMARY` or to a `UNIQUE` key of another table.

Comment: I never thought at that. I think you are right. W3schools is obsolete :)

Comment: CREATE  TABLE STUDENT(SID NUMBER,NAME VARCHAR2(20),DEPT VARCHAR2(20),
CARD_F NUMBER,CARD_S NUMBER,PRIMARY KEY(SID,CARD_F,CARD_S));
CREATE TABLE MASTER(BOOKNO NUMBER,CARD_S NUMBER,
FOREIGN KEY(BOOKNO) REFERENCES STUDENT(CARD_F));

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd for bookno to take its values from a column named card_f.

There are several different ways this incorrect reference

```
, FOREIGN KEY (BOOKNO) 
    REFERENCES STUDENT(CARD_F)
```

can be fixed.

1. Create a primary key constraint on student.card_f.
2. Create a unique constraint on student.card_f.
3. Reference a different table that has either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint on a bookno column, possibly something like books.bookno.
4. Create a primary key or unique constraint on the pair of columns {card_s, card_f} in the student table, and  reference that with `foreign key (card_s, card_f) references student (card_s, card_f)`.
5. Add the SID column to master, and reference the full key with `foreign key (sid, card_s, bookno) references student (sid, card_s, card_f)`.

Of those, 3, 4, and 5 are the most likely to work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Options :

```
1> Please check if you can create a unique Key on the two columns on the base table the you want to refer to.

2> a)If you cant create unique key then intoduce a 3rd table which would maintain 
    distinct combination of column values for columns, to be included in F.K.
    through a trigger on base table.

   b)Make columns in your child table refer(F.K) to this newly introduced table
```